# Galois group of $X^3-10$ over $\mathbb{Q} (i\sqrt{3})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, galois-theory

This is Exercise 1(d), page 320 in Lang's Algebra.

I think that the Galois group is in this case simply the trivial group $\{Id\}$.

Why?

Let:

$$f(X)=X^3-10.$$

Then the splitting field of $f$ is given by $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{10}, \varsigma_3)=:E$, where $\varsigma_3$ is the 3rd root of unity.

Now, any embedding

$$\varphi: E \rightarrow [\mathbb{Q} (i\sqrt{3})]^a,$$

where $k^a$ denotes the closure, must induce the identity on $\mathbb{Q} (i\sqrt{3})$. Therefore we have that:

$$\varphi(i\sqrt{3})=i\sqrt{3}$$.

Thus, for any $\sigma \in Gal(p, \mathbb{Q} (i\sqrt{3}))$, we have:

$$\sigma(\varsigma^i_3)=\varsigma^i_3,$$

and, a fortiori, $\sigma(\sqrt[3]{10})=\sqrt[3]{10}$.

I was just checking if this actually make sense. Thanks!

Comment: Not right. Writing the real cube root of $10$ as $\lambda$, you can always send $\lambda$ to $\zeta_3\lambda$. Of course you do need to have checked that $X^3-10$ is still irreducible over $\Bbb Q(\zeta_3)$, but that’s not hard.

Comment: You know that $[E:\Bbb{Q}]=6$, right? As $E$ is Galois over $\Bbb{Q}$ it is also Galois over any intermediate field $K$ (it's still the splitting field of $x^3-10$ over $K$). Therefore the number of $K$-automorphisms of $E$ is $[E:K]$. Time to rethink - follow prof. Lubin's advice.

Answer (score 1):

$K=Q(i\sqrt{3})=Q(w)$ for $w$ a primitive cube root of 1. The roots or $f=x^3-10$ are $a, aw, aw^2$ for $a=\sqrt[3]{10}$. So the splitting field of $f$ over $K$ is $K(a)$ of degree 3. Thus the Galois group is cyclic of order 3 generated by $a\rightarrow aw$.

Comment: $(aw)^3=a^3w^3=10*1$